# I am getting null response for my nested DTO field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, dto

{
"firstName": "User43",
"lastName": "Test43",
"login": "Test43",
"email": "test43@mail.com",
"creationDate": "2022-10-11",
"sourceSystemDto": null
}

[image: Below is UserDTO]

[image: SourceSystemDTO]

Comment: Add code as text not as image. Also provide an [mcve]

Comment: okay will keep in mind . if you know please help me solve this. thankyou

Comment: What are you trying to do? Serialization or deserialization? a little bit more context will be fine

Comment: I am doing serialization where I am setting the value of sourceSystem filed manually (hardcoded) and other fields I am passing as RequestBody

Comment: Can you show the code please?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding @JsonBackReference to your SourceSystemDto entity and add a mapping to your entity
Like below:

let's say your parent entity is named student

```
@Entity
public class Student{
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
@NotNull
@JsonProperty(value="sourceSystemDto")
@OneToOne
private SourceSystemDto sourcceSystemDto;
```

for the second table

```
    @Entity
    public class SourceSystemDto{

    
    @NotNull
    private String sourceSystem;
@JsonBackReference
private Student parent;//give name to parent entity here
    }
```

Try this . It should work

Comment: You can use mapping as per your preference . However, in above example i have used OneToOne

Comment: Also, please show the code if this is not what you are trying to acheive